# How to preprocess a column with too many NAN values?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, machine-learning, nan

I have a training data of shape `(596000, 58)` and below image has some of the features vs number of "NAN"s in the features/rows using `train.isnull().sum()`.

Considering each feature has equal importance and are categorical values **Should I remove the column cat6 and cat8?** as for `cat6` 411792/596000 are NaNs and for `cat8` 266928/596000 are NaNs.

Is there a way to deal with this situation ? or I have to remove both the columns ?

---

input [12]: `train.isnull().sum()`

output [12]:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There're few possible strategies with missing value for categorical features:

- remove feature;
- for the *NaN* values set the most frequent value of this feature;
- for the *NaN* values set the new class (for instance, *nan_value*);
- the most complex approach - create a separate model for predict missing values for the current feature;

What fits best? Look deeper into your data. Build a simple baseline model and try all approaches. That should helps answer for your question.

In your case, seems, yes the features cat6 and cat8 are useless for you, but you still need to short investigation of this question.

Comment: I used EDA on both train and test samples, the result was cat6 had same missing values, and cat8 missing was quite less. So should i remove cat6 and create a new class ? The target is only 0/1, so I think making a new class for NaNs should be good enough...

Comment: I would suggest, try different approaches using some simple model:
- remove cat6 and can8 columns;
- remove cat6 and create new class for the missing values from the can8 columns;
....

After that, you can compare scores and choose the best approach

Answer (score 0):

Removing both `cat6` and `cat8` is best here.
As you have 500k values, assuming all the above values are categorical, rest you can make a `new category` for rest NaN values of other features.